# date and time are off after update/reboot

Tags: debian

I am using Debian 11 (on stable channel). Today I installed a few updates (got notified in the Software app) and after reboot my date and time are off.

My year is now set to `2043`. The BIOS time was off too, but by only a few hours. So after I corrected the BIOS time and rebooted, the time in Debian was only off by a few hours.

Then in Debian in settings I checked "Automatic Date & Time" (although I'm pretty sure I had it checked before) and the time went back to year `2043`!

I ran `timedatectl status` and got this output:

```
Local time: Thu 2043-03-26 19:27:04 +07
           Universal time: Thu 2043-03-26 12:27:04 UTC
                 RTC time: Sat 2022-03-26 21:12:48
                Time zone: Asia/Bangkok (+07, +0700)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

The `RTC time` seems correct (that's actually the time right now in my location), everything else is off.

Please suggest how to fix this.

**Update**:

If I run `sudo systemctl status systemd-timesyncd` command (looks like I don't have `ntp` installed) I get the following output.

```
systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Synchronization...
systemd-timesyncd[4247]: System clock time unset or jumped backwards, restoring from recorded timestamp: Thu 2043-03-26 19:03:58 +07
systemd[1]: Started Network Time Synchronization.
```

Comment: Might be a dead clock coin cell, often easily replaced.

Comment: Whatever the underlying problem that happened (and might still happen), looks like timesyncd tries to be smart and fails: it won't set back the time. Use a direct command, like `ntpdate -b 2.debian.pool.ntp.org` or even good old `date`. Beware, changing time over a wide period can disrupt some running tools including the GUI.